# Will it better to use isInterrupted instead of interrupted in the following case

Tags: java, multithreading

When I revise some old code, I came across.

```
public void stop() {
    if (this.simulationThread != null) {
        this.simulationThread.interrupt();

        try {
            this.simulationThread.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException exp) {
            log.error(null, exp);
        }

        this.simulationThread = null;
     }
}

public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted() && simulationThread == Thread.currentThread()) {
    }
}
```

I was wondering, will it better to use, or it doesn't matter?

```
public void run() {
    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    // Will it better to use isInterrupted, since it will not clear the interrupt
    // flag?
    while (!t.isInterrupted() && simulationThread == t) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you intend to happen when `run()` exits. If your `run()` function is your main thread loop, such that you want that thread to exit immediately upon `run()` completing, then swallowing the interruption flag with `Thread#interrupted()` is fine.

Usually, though, that's not what you want to do. If you're trying to enable graceful exit of the `run()` function to allow cooperative cancellation, it's better form to preserve the interrupted flag for your caller and for downstream blocking functions to detect. For that, using `Thread#isInterrupted()` is the better choice.

Note that in your `stop()` function, where you catch `InterruptedException`, you should also call

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

It's not clear from the snippets posted here who is calling `stop()` and what's supposed to happen afterward, but, again, it would be better form to preserve the interruption flag that popped `stop()` out of `Thread#join()`. Just catching `InterruptedException` allows `stop()` to react to that interruption, but no callers or following blocking functions would be able to detect that interruption request against the current thread. In other words, interrupting a thread is rarely satisfied by just unblocking one blocking function call; the interruption request *usually* needs to propagate all the way back out to the thread's main function so that it may exit.

Finally, is your `simulationThread` field volatile?